# Implementing Patience Sort with LinkedList

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, stack

According to my notes, the patience sort divides data into a number of bins, and then combines the contents of those bins into a complete list.

I think I get the general idea of how to do this, but one of the requirements is to have a `LinkedList` for the list of `ints`, the list of `stacks`, and the `stack` itself.

So what confuses me, is how I'm suppose to `add` each `stack` to the `LinkedList`, when the `LinkedList` accepts `ints`, not `stacks`. I could change the `LinkedList` to accept `stacks`, but then when I originally created the list to be sorted in the `main` method, it was done with `ints`.

I know I'm missing something obvious, but I can't see how this can be done, any suggestions? I've included my sort method below, with some commented out code of how things could be done (but I'm not sure if it is right).

```
public void sort() {
    LinkedList listOfStacks = new LinkedList();
    //LinkedList<Stacks> listOfStacks = new LinkedList()<Stacks>;
    int [] listOfInts =  {8, 5, 3, 4, 1, 2, 6, 9, 7};

    for(int i = 0; i < listOfInts.length; i++) {
        LinkedList stack = new LinkedList();
        // No stacks initially, create first stack,
        // and add first element
        if(listOfStacks.getSize() == 0) {
            // listOfStacks.add(stack);
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < listOfStacks.getSize(); j++) {
            if(stack.getSize() == 0) {
                stack.push(listOfInts[i]);
                // listOfStacks.add(stack);
            }
            else if(stack.peek() < listOfInts[i]) {
                stack.push(listOfInts[i]);
                // listOfStacks.add(stack);
                break;
            }
            else {
                LinkedList newStack = new LinkedList();
                newStack.push(listOfInts[i]);
                // listOfStacks.add(newStack);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to add the stack to the linked list directly, pop values off the stack into the linked list until the stack is empty.

Alternatively, if you may declare your linked list of stacks to accept other linked lists, rather than ints:

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> listOfStacks = new LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
```

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, as in for `LinkedList piles`, add all the values for the specific stack. However, won't this just create a list of nodes in the `LinkedList piles` rather than sorted piles?

Comment: Indeed, you'll end up with a single linked list of nodes, however, the order of the nodes is representative of the stacks in which they were first sorted. If you require to maintain the distinction between stacks, you just need to properly declare a linked list that accepts stacks, see my edit above.